# Transform value of Selector

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, testcafe, ui-testing

I have a HTML element `<div id="the-value">30 000</div>` for which the content is calculated.

I need to assert the value of this element to be a valid number (>= 20000), however, the value property returns a string and I cannot assert it using `.gte()`

This assertion fails with: `AssertionError: expected '30 000' to be a number or a date`

```
await t.expect(Selector('#the-value').value).gte(20000);
```

How can I transform the string to a number before assertion?

Comment: You can't convert it with ```parseInt()``` to a number before evaluating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using testcafe, you should be able to await the Selector and run the test later on it. So you could do:

```
const selector = await Selector('#the-value').value;
const selectorNumber = parseInt(selector);

await t.expect(selectorNumber).gte(20000);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Since the value comes from a backend server, I hat to put a `.wait(2000)` before.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Did not think of that possibilty. Glad that it works now.

Answer (score -1):

`.expect(+Selector('#the-value').value).gte(20000)`

Plus sign converts string to number, hopefully this will work

Another way would be to use parseInt as it will fail silently if the values in string isn't a valid number

Comment: This does not work. `.value` returns a `Promise<string>`

Comment: This is gonna sound weird but how about awaiting value first and then converting the value into number?